# What is the French equivalent of “A hollow box-shaped vessel.”?

Tags: constructions

### Scenario

**Boy A**: During the night, my friend and I were lying down outside in the hayfield.

**Boy B**: And?

**Boy A**: We saw a spaceship. It was a hollow box-shaped vessel.”

*By the word **hollow** I mean that the spaceship is empty and the boys could see the box-shaped vessel was hollow because it was made of glass.*

---

I’m trying to figure out the French equivalent of “A hollow box-shaped vessel.” I’ve arrived at « Un vaisseau creux façonné comme une boîte ». However, I feel like there is a shorter way to say **“a hollow box-shaped vessel.”** :/

What is the French equivalent of **“a hollow box-shaped vessel.”**?

Comment: *Un vaisseau en forme de boîte creuse* ? Pas très joli, j'espère que quelqu'un proposera mieux.

Comment: @Damien Pourquoi ne pas mettre aux voix cette réponse ? Mieux vaut l'avoir en réponse qu'en commentaire à mon avis.

Comment: Nous vîmes un astronef. C'était un engin/appareil/vaisseau en forme de caisson vide.

Comment: @Personne Quel objet de la vie de tous les jours a la forme de ou est un _caisson_ ?

Comment: Donnez/montrez-nous notre *astronef* quotidien ? … caisson est une caisse/un volume avec un but technique précis, quelques exemples types : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caisson

Answer (score 2):

> Un vaisseau en forme de boîte creuse. [*Damien*, en [commentaire]](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44290/what-is-the-french-equivalent-of-a-hollow-box-shaped-vessel#comment90134_44290)

Answer (score 1):

> Un [vaisseau spatial](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vaisseau_spatial) ([translucide](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/translucide)/[transparent](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/transparent)) en [forme](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/forme) de cube et [vide](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/vide#Adjectif) (au centre/à l'intérieur)[in the center/inside].

Comment: Thank you for your help!  By the word **“hollow”** I mean the spaceship is empty. The boys could see that the cube was hollow because the material of the sides of the cube was quite transparent. Does this clarification change your answer?

Comment: Nope. Hm... Let’s see... The material the cube was made out of was glass.

Comment: Would the french equivalent be « Un vaisseau en forme de cube creux » ?

Comment: Understood! *vide* it is! Thank you so much @Thélée_Lavoie ! 

Comment: What does *spatial translucide* mean?

Comment: Maybe someone can think further inside the box, so to speak!

Answer (score 0):

> Nous vîmes un astronef. C'était un engin/appareil/vaisseau en forme de
> caisson vide. [*Personne*, en [commentaire]](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44290/what-is-the-french-equivalent-of-a-hollow-box-shaped-vessel#comment91175_44290)